# Supplying NTC by different voltage from VCC

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, stm32, adc, thermistor

I would like the sense a material temperature that is located outside of panel. My NTC thermistor is 10meter far from my STM32 MCU based control board. I don't want to use VCC at outside of the panel because there are alots ot motors and noise sources.
MCU is energized by 3.3VDC and my panel have 24VDC. So I want to connect 24VDC to top of NTC.

[image]

My questions are:

1. Using more voltage divider resistors to decrease Vout to 0-3.3V range
   is enough? If yes, how can I connect grounds while keeping isolation?
2. For better way How can I make true isolation between MCu and Vout of thermistor

Comment: 100k is far too high resistance in case you mean to attach a cable to this. It will be EMI sensitive like crazy. Why do you need such huge resistor values?

Comment: Actually It is not exact value. I can change it on the suggestions.

Comment: What I think you should do is to create a current loop with a rail-to-rail or current sense OP with the output connected to the base of a BJT, then on the MCU side measure the current. Ideally industry standard 4-20mA but perhaps that's not important here. Then you can have fairly long cables no problem. I'm far too shaky at analog electronics to attempt to post a schematic as answer though. Also, it isn't obvious if you should use NTC or PTC.

Comment: @Lundin Actually I have no space to put 4-20mA generator circuit at outside. So I have to use  only NTC resistor and long cable at outsite. Sum up, my cables can carry just voltage not  current

Comment: It wouldn't be a big PCB. In worst case you can skip the PCB and make the current generator with a bunch of THR components soldered together - then wrap it all in heat-shrink tubing. Classic quick & dirty solution that's usually fairly rugged.

Comment: @Lundin But this circuit must stand 400C temperature. Maybe ı must find without any circuit that is on ousite of panel.

Comment: You kind of forgot to mention that little detail in the question... It means that you can't use standard components.

Comment: Why does it say -24VDC and GND, as well as -3.3V and GND? Which is it?

Comment: @winny I have drawn like that  in order to show of  separated grounds

Comment: Please don’t. It causes confusion. Call them GND_5V and GND_24V or something similar. “-“ means negative voltage.

Answer (score 3):

You would not be bringing Vcc off the board, but Vcc through a resistor (perhaps 10K). Not the same thing at all.

You can add a ferrite bead to the ground connection to keep the 'antenna' from bouncing your ground around, and use shielded wires. Then filter and maybe buffer (if necessary) the signal before it goes to the ADC.

Edit: assuming your ground is earthed, something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDrsi0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You say just bring Vcc and Gnd off the board.  Circuit something like that : [Circuit](https://i.ibb.co/wJLTLZp/IMG-20201007-160046.jpg)  Will external noise not effect to my ground ?

Comment: After Your Edition: You have drawn similar circuit that on my comment. As I said before there is very noisy environment , the 10 meter cable is not solid. 4 connector passages on the cable. You say I don't need any optoisolation system or something like that ? I'm asking because I'm very scared about noise

Comment: You might, but you have not asked about an analog opto (or other means) isolator. If you replace FB with a relatively high value resistor same as R3 you could use an external regulated 3.3V supply and resistor which would be somewhat better than the FB. Depending on the grounding, your system susceptibility, and so on.